# Criar gatilho para exclusão de dados antigos Mysql

Tags: mysql, trigger, delete

Bom dia.

tenho uma tabela "dados" nessa tabela são gravados varias informações como 'user_id' e 'time';

Gostaria de criar um gatilho para quando inserir um dado novo excluir o mais antigos que 90 dias.

Na linha de comando MySQL fica assim:

```
DELETE FROM `dados` WHERE `user_id` = user_id AND `time` < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 90 DAY));
```

Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: O que você tentou até aqui? O que você espera que aconteça caso essa tabela não receba nenhuma informação daquele usuário em 90 dias?

Comment: Eu criei o gatilho pelo phpmyadmin, e ele retorna um erro, estou sem acesso aqui mais assim que tiver acesso aqui posto o erro.

Comment: Caso não receba informações não faça nada. Na verdade esse seria um outro gatilho para ser executado em outro momento, mas se tiver outra ideia. Estará.

Comment: "Can't update table 'dados' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger"

Comment: Esse é o erro que aparece quando cadastro o gatiho